# Where to put excel template file in django project

Tags: python, django, excel, openpyxl, django-staticfiles

In my Django application users can get excel file for necessary data. I'm using **openpyxl** library for manipulating excel files. What i want to do is use an formatted excel file as an template for the file users download. I tryed to put my "template.xlsx" under static and other places but i couldn't reach file anyway.

This is how I open my excel file in the correspoding view:

```
filename = r'static\app1\template.xlsx'
    workbook = load_workbook(filename)
```

Also I'm not sure where to put my excel template file, neither how to get path to it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I would create some sort of `resources` directory.
My directory structure would be something like this:

```
project
----core
--------settings.py
--------urls.py
--------wsgi.py
----app1
--------resources
------------template.xlsx
--------views.py
```

You would then work with it like this:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

filename = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'app1', 'resource', 'template.xlsx')
workbook = load_workbook(filename)
```

Also, I would highly suggest you don't do this kind of logic (or any kind of business logic) in views. Either use "fat models thin controllers" or introduce new service layer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will consider your suggestion about business logic and try to refactor my code asap.